# Display data on different browser tabs

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, cross-browser

The browser has two tabs opened with the different URL.

The data received by one html page from server...

Is it possible to display the same data in another tab which is already opened  without reloading...If so how should that has to  be done...

Comment: Yes, it is _"possible to display the same data in another tab which is already opened without reloading"_.

Next!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, **if** either:

1. Your code opened the other tab (via `window.open`), or
2. The window has a *name* (such as one assigned via the `target` attribute on a link, e.g. `target="otherwindow"`)

Additionally, the window's content must be on the same origin as the document you're interacting with it from, or you'll be blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

#### 1. If you're opening it via `window.open`

`window.open` returns a reference to the `window` object for the window that was opened, which (assuming it's on the same origin) you can do things with. E.g.:

```
var wnd = window.open("/some/url");

// ...later, when it's loaded...

var div = wnd.document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "content";
wnd.document.appendChild(div);
```

You can use all of the usual DOM methods. If you load a library in the other window, you can use that as well. (It's important to understand that the two windows have two different global namespaces, they're not shared.)

Here's a full example. I used jQuery in the below just for convenience, but jQuery is **not** required for this. As I said above, you can use the DOM directly (or another library if you like):

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ecaguq/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ecaguq/1/edit)

HTML:

```
<button id="btnOpen">Open Window</button>
<button id="btnAdd">Add Content</button>
<button id="btnRemove">Remove Content</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function($) {
  var btnOpen,
      btnAdd,
      btnRemove,
      wnd,
      wndTimeout,
      wnd$,
      newContentId = 0;

  btnOpen   = $("#btnOpen");
  btnAdd    = $("#btnAdd");
  btnRemove = $("#btnRemove");
  updateButtons();

  btnOpen.click(openWindow);
  btnAdd.click(addContent);
  btnRemove.click(removeContent);

  function updateButtons() {
    btnOpen[0].disabled = !!wnd;
    btnAdd[0].disabled = !wnd$;
    btnRemove[0].disabled = !wnd$;
  }

  function openWindow() {
    if (!wnd) {
      display("Opening window");
      wnd$ = undefined;
      wndTimeout = new Date().getTime() + 10000;
      wnd = window.open("/etogel/1");
      updateButtons();
      checkReady();
    }
  }

  function windowClosed() {
    display("Other window was closed");
    wnd = undefined;
    wnd$ = undefined;
    updateButtons();
  }

  function checkReady() {
    if (wnd && wnd.jQuery) {
      wnd$ = wnd.jQuery;
      wnd$(wnd).on("unload", windowClosed);
      updateButtons();
    }
    else {
      if (new Date().getTime() > wndTimeout) {
        display("Timed out waiting for other window to be ready");
        wnd = undefined;
      }
      else {
        setTimeout(checkReady, 10);
      }
    }
  }

  function addContent() {
    var div;

    if (wnd$) {
      ++newContentId;
      display("Adding content '" + newContentId + "'");
      wnd$("<div>").addClass("ourcontent").html("Added content block #" + newContentId).appendTo(wnd.document.body);
    }
  }

  function removeContent() {
    var div;

    if (wnd$) {
      div = wnd$("div.ourcontent").first();
      if (div[0]) {
        display("Removing div '" + div.html() + "' from other window");
        div.remove();
      }
      else {
        display("None of our content divs found in other window, not removing anything");
      }
    }
  }

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
  }

})(jQuery);
```

#### 2. If you're opening it via a link with `target`

`window.open` can find and return a reference to that window:

```
var wnd = window.open("", "otherwindow");
```

Note that the URL argument is empty, but we pass it the name from the `target` attribute. The window must *already* be open for this to work (otherwise it will open a completely blank window).

Here's the above example, modified to assume you've opened the window via `<a href="..." target="otherwindow">...</a>`:

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ecaguq/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ecaguq/2/edit)

HTML:

```
<a href="/etogel/1" target="otherwindow">Click to open the other window</a>
<br><button id="btnGet">Get Window</button>
<button id="btnAdd">Add Content</button>
<button id="btnRemove">Remove Content</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function($) {
  var btnGet,
      btnAdd,
      btnRemove,
      wnd,
      wndTimeout,
      wnd$,
      newContentId = 0;

  btnGet    = $("#btnGet");
  btnAdd    = $("#btnAdd");
  btnRemove = $("#btnRemove");
  updateButtons();

  btnGet.click(getWindow);
  btnAdd.click(addContent);
  btnRemove.click(removeContent);

  function updateButtons() {
    btnGet[0].disabled = !!wnd;
    btnAdd[0].disabled = !wnd$;
    btnRemove[0].disabled = !wnd$;
  }

  function getWindow() {
    if (!wnd) {
      display("Getting 'otherwindow' window");
      wnd$ = undefined;
      wndTimeout = new Date().getTime() + 10000;
      wnd = window.open("", "otherwindow");
      updateButtons();
      checkReady();
    }
  }

  function windowClosed() {
    display("Other window was closed");
    wnd = undefined;
    wnd$ = undefined;
    updateButtons();
  }

  function checkReady() {
    if (wnd && wnd.jQuery) {
      wnd$ = wnd.jQuery;
      wnd$(wnd).on("unload", windowClosed);
      updateButtons();
    }
    else {
      if (new Date().getTime() > wndTimeout) {
        display("Timed out looking for other window");
        wnd = undefined;
        updateButtons();
      }
      else {
        setTimeout(checkReady, 10);
      }
    }
  }

  function addContent() {
    var div;

    if (wnd$) {
      ++newContentId;
      display("Adding content '" + newContentId + "'");
      wnd$("<div>").addClass("ourcontent").html("Added content block #" + newContentId).appendTo(wnd.document.body);
    }
  }

  function removeContent() {
    var div;

    if (wnd$) {
      div = wnd$("div.ourcontent").first();
      if (div[0]) {
        display("Removing div '" + div.html() + "' from other window");
        div.remove();
      }
      else {
        display("None of our content divs found in other window, not removing anything");
      }
    }
  }

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
  }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the contents of other window

Comment: @Aravind: Yup, as I said, you can use all the usual DOM stuff. So you can use `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName`, `innerHTML`, `removeChild`, `insertBefore`, etc.

Comment: When i using the code  window.open("/some/url"); new window get opened..it doesn't consider the tab which is already opened

Comment: @Aravind: Yes. As I said above, you can do this **if** your code opened the other tab via `window.open`. You can also do it if the window was opened via a link with a `target` attribute, if you gave the target a name (e.g., `target="othertab"`), because you can get a reference to that other window using that name, like this: `wnd = window.open("", "othertab");` (note the URL is blank, and then I use the window name in the second argument).

Comment: @Aravind: I've added full examples of both mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code and spend your time to answer me... .I found another code bit  like this .....window.opener.document.getElement("").innerHTML="";..... both of it working for me ...

Comment: @Aravind: Yes, that's the converse -- it's what you would do in the *other* window if you wanted to update the content in the window that opened it.